# How to I get setTimeout to work a second time in a chain of functions (instead of making the page freeze)?

Tags: jquery, function, settimeout, chaining

So I want to make a chain of functions happen every time I click the body (or any type of element; I’m just using the body for testing, and I have the following code. However, when I click the body a second time, it causes the webpage to freeze. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
var doging = false;
var first;
var second;
var third;

$("body").click(function(){
    if(doging == false)
    {
        clearTimeout(first);
        clearTimeout(second);
        clearTimeout(third);
        wow();
    }
});

function wow(){
    doging = true;
    $("#doge_text").text("Wow");
    color();
    size();
    first = setTimeout(function(){wow2();}, 1500);
}

function wow2(){
    $("#doge_text").text("Such doge");
    color2();
    size();
    second = setTimeout(function(){wow3();}, 1500);
}

function wow3(){
    $("#doge_text").text("Very click");
    color3();
    size();
    third = setTimeout(function(){wow4();}, 1500);
}

function wow4(){
    $("#doge_text").text("").css({"height": "0", "width": "0"});
    doging = false;
}
```

Comment: What do `colorN` and `size` functions do?

Comment: I can't see anything in that script that would cause a page freeze. Can you set up a minimal *complete* case?

Comment: Yeah, something with some test input, and a couple timeouts on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `wow4()` sets the height and width of the `#doge_text` element to zero.  So, on the second click when you go into `size()`, `w` and `h` are always zero, no matter how big you make the font, thus you get an infinite loop in `size()`.

A fix would be to never enter a sequence with the height or width set to `0`.  `#doge_text` must be allowed to resize itself to the text font in order for the `size()` loop to ever work.

FYI, I was able to zero in on this by just placing `console.log()` statements throughout the progress.  That led me to see that it was getting hung up in the `size()` function and I then set a breakpoint in that function and stepped through after the second click until I could see that `w` and `h` were always zero.

You can fix it by removing the set of  `height` and `width` to zero  in `wow4()` as they shouldn't be needed because you've already cleared the text:

```
function wow4(){
    $("#doge_text").text("");
    doging = false;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hDvqg/

---

FYI, there are a couple of odd practices in your code:

1. You have local variables (only used locally within one function) declared globally such as `w` and `h`.  These really should be declared as local variables within the function they are used in.
2. There appears to be no reason to have the `clearTimeout()` statements at all because you don't have a means of cancelling the timers and once they have executed, there's no reason to cancel them.